# unit test a node.js controller that call external api

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express

How do I test below module/function where it calls external api? If I'm firing the api that's not unit test anymore, that's call intergration or flow testing. I know there's such thing call mock api, but what it should test? I expect only 2 outcome, it fail or it succeed. Since the external api already handle edge case (says name param is not supply), do I have to do unit testing on my side?

```
const request = require('request')
import PATH from './config/somewhere'

export const createUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    response = await request.post(`${PATH}/api/user/create`, {form: {name: req.body.name}})
    res.json(response)
  } catch(err) {
    this.throw(err.message)
  }
}
```

Comment: If you had extra logic after this call or any transformation before data reaches here, etc.., you should test that functionality by mocking. Otherwise this would be covered in Integration or e2e etc.., no point in unit testing this IMO.

Comment: You need to mock the `request` module.

Answer (score 0):

See:
https://github.com/node-nock/nock

You can call the following code when initializing your tests:

```
const nock = require('nock');

// ...

nock(`${PATH}/api/user`)
    .post('/create')
    .reply(200, { data: 'foo' });

// ...
// All calls to request from here will be intercepted by nock
```

Comment: Can you write more? will you actually make a real http call in this case?

Comment: Your code doesn't change, you call the nock before running any http requests.
You can follow this blog post:
https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/mocking-external-http-requests-in-node-tests-with-nock